# Use RestKit in static library and the project

Tags: ios, static-libraries, restkit, static-linking

I have a static library which uses RestKit internally (but does not expose RestKit: headers etc).

I want to use this static library in a project which uses RestKit already.

As expected, I get duplicate symbols.

How do I get around this? 
Can I build my static library without "bundling" in RestKit?

It would be ideal if my static library can use RestKit, but not include it.

Comment: If you build the static library then make the RestKit contents available for use in the project...

Answer (score 0):

If you know which version of RestKit the static library uses, you could just download the headers of that version in your project, and call its objects/methods normally.

When building the project, if the other static library compiles internally the implementations of that library, when the linker should find the symbols.